# Magento 1.9 I need add qty in category page and mask should not load

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart, ajax, ajaxaddtocart

My template used **ajax** cart
this code in my category page(list.phtml)

```
<a href="<?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory", $code) && !Mage::getStoreConfig("tnd        _settings/category/qty_field", $code)): ?>
<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?><?php else: ?>javascript:void(0)<?php endif; ?>" class="addtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" 
<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory", $code)):?>onclick="setLocationAjax(this,'<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>'
,'<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')"<?php elseif(Mage::getStoreConfig("tnd_settings/category/qty_field", $code)): ?>onclick="document.getElementById('addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>').submit()"<?php endif; ?>><i class="icon-cart"></i><span>&nbsp;<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></a>
```

A number is added when the user clicks on add to cart and load the mask in page
i need the user to be able to enter the number of need the product on this page
**of course by an number input**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for this problem

```
<div class="qty-field">
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
<div class="qty-holder"><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" maxlength="6" value="<?php echo $product->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
<div class="qty-changer">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_inc"><i class="icon-up-dir"></i></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_dec"><i class="icon-down-dir"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
<a href="<?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory", $code) && !Mage::getStoreConfig("tng_settings/category/qty_field", $code)): ?><?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?><?php else: ?>javascript:void(0)<?php endif; ?>" class="addtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory", $code)):?>onclick="setLocationAjax(this,'<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')"<?php elseif(Mage::getStoreConfig("tng_settings/category/qty_field", $code)): ?>onclick="document.getElementById('addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>').submit()"<?php endif; ?>><i class="icon-cart"></i><span>&nbsp;<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></a>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <a href="<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory", $code)):?>javascript:showOptions('<?php echo $_product->getId()?>')<?php else: ?><?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?><?php endif; ?>" class="addtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>"><i class="icon-cart"></i><span>&nbsp;<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></a>
                                <a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajaxcart/index/options',array('product_id'=>$_product->getId()));?>' class='fancybox' id='fancybox<?php echo $_product->getId()?>' style='display:none'>Options</a>
```